# Instapy doesn't see post when searching for tags

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, instapy

i'm trying to make a bot for instagram and i have started to use instapy so i am looking if it is all okay.
The library is very buggy, i have already commented two lines of code to execute the login(shared_data null problem: https://github.com/InstaPy/InstaPy/issues/6632) and it seems to work.
Now i'm trying to execute the rest of quickstart script, but it seems to not find posts when run like_by_tags function.
I take a look in code, but don't know if it is a xpath problem or another problem with the code.

quickstart script:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

session = InstaPy(username="CENSORED", password="CENSORED", want_check_browser=False)
session.login()
session.set_quota_supervisor(enabled=True, peak_comments_daily=240, peak_comments_hourly=21)
session.set_do_follow(True, percentage=50)
session.set_do_comment(True, percentage=50)
session.set_comments(["Nice!", "Sweet!", "Beautiful :heart_eyes:"])
session.like_by_tags(["bmw", "mercedes"], amount=5)
session.set_dont_like(["naked", "nsfw"])
session.end()
```

the Output:

```
INFO [2023-06-15 15:22:21] [longo._.al]  Tag [1/2]
INFO [2023-06-15 15:22:21] [longo._.al]  --> b'bmw'
INFO [2023-06-15 15:22:58] [longo._.al]  Too few images, skipping this tag
INFO [2023-06-15 15:22:58] [longo._.al]  Tag [2/2]
INFO [2023-06-15 15:22:58] [longo._.al]  --> b'mercedes'
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Too few images, skipping this tag
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Liked: 0
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Already Liked: 0
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Commented: 0
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Followed: 0
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Inappropriate: 0
INFO [2023-06-15 15:23:32] [longo._.al]  Not valid users: 0
```

Need some tip to make the script working.